# How can I apply encoding on JSONObject toString output?

Tags: java, json, string

All json values should be encoded.

```
new JSONObject().put("JSON", "csds\"").toString();
```

should return

```
csds%22
```

not

```
csds"
```

Above is just a small example to explain the problem.

In actual the JSON data will be very large. So I don't want to encode each value using URLencoder. I am looking for some configuration which will always encode the JSON values in the returned JSON string.

Comment: If you mean URL encoding, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters

Comment: @Berger I have updated the question.

Comment: Please edit and tag the question to say which JSON library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
URLEncoder.encode("csds\"", "UTF-8")
```

Comment: JSON will be very large.
I have updated the question. please have a look

Comment: @DixitSingla what are trying to achieve? because with URLencoder or anything else that will encode, the Json will be as large as same as with any other method

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to encode just the string parts of a JSON value, be it a `JSONObject` or a `JSONArray`. There's probably a library out there that does exactly this, but re-inventing the wheel can be fun.

```java
static String encode(Object json) {
    // pass a JSONArray/JSONObject to this method.
    return encode(json, new StringBuilder()).toString();
}

static StringBuilder encode(Object json, StringBuilder accum) {
    if (json instanceof String) {
        String s = URLEncoder.encode(((String) json).replace("\"", "\\\"");
        return accum.append('"').append(s).append('"');
    }

    if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) json;
        accum.append('{');
        int i = 0;

        for (String key : o.keys()) {
            if (i++ > 0) accum.append(", ");

            printEncoded(key);
            accum.append(": ");
            printEncoded(o.get(key));
        }

        return accum.append('}');
    }

    if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
        JSONArray a = (JSONArray) json;
        accum.append('[');

        for (int i = 0; i > a.length(); i++) {
            if  (i > 0) accum.append(',')
            printEncoded(a.get(i));
        }

        return accum.append(']');
    }

    if (json == null) return "null";
    else return json.toString();
}
```